# Failed to build the app after I installed react-native-push-notification

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

I installed react-native-push-notification from ([React Native Push Notifications](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/f8f9841772dec5c5249a75db6b87a4b2d901d0c2/README.md)) and I can not run the app on android. I did not test on IOS

```
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Zarzu Victor\payAssistant\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\build.gradle' line: 47

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-push-notification'.
> Could not get unknown property 'DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also facing this issue, starting from today. I found that `googlePlayServicesVersion` is missing from `android/build.gradle`. Added line below and it solved the issue with the library.

```
// android/build.gradle

buildscript {
    ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "+" // <- add this line
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it

Comment: Another question. Do you know how to upgrade to Google Play Developer API 3.0?

Comment: Its missing, but why is it needed?